# The derivative of $ \ln\left(\frac{x+2}{x^3-1}\right)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, logarithms

I know it is a simple question, but what would be the next few steps in this equation to find the derivative?

$$f(x)= \ln\left(\frac{x+2}{x^3-1}\right)$$

Comment: Have you tried using the chain rule here?

Comment: do i find the derivative of ln for both the numerator and denominator?

Comment: Yes, you'll have to find the derivative of them combined, using the quotient rule.

Comment: oh wow, makes sense

Comment: You could use the property $\ln \frac{u}{v} = \ln u - \ln v$ before you differentiate.

Comment: @HDE226868 : You're mistaken.  One does not _have to_ use the quotient rule for this.  See my answer below. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy I used "have" for the first part of my response; Cheng was asking whether or not both the numerator and the denominator needed to be dealt with. The answer to that is, of course, yes. I apologize if I caused confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $$f(x)= \ln\left(\frac{x+2}{x^3-1}\right)$$
Start by re-writing the logarithm as
$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\ln\left(\frac{x+2}{x^3-1}\right)\right)=\frac{d}{dx}\left(\ln({x+2})-\ln({x^3-1})\right)$$$$=\frac{d}{dx}\left(\ln({x+2})\right)-\frac{d}{dx}\left(\ln({x^3-1})\right)= \color{blue}{\frac{1}{x+2}-\frac{3x^2}{x^3-1}}$$

Answer (score 4):

Let:

$$h(x) = \ln(x) \hspace{.3cm} \text{and} \hspace{.3cm} g(x) = \frac{x + 2}{x^3 - 1}$$

so that:

$$f(x) = h(g(x))$$

Now using the chain rule:

$$f'(x) = h'(g(x))g'(x)$$

Comment: I don't think that is the best way to do this.  (See my answer.)

Comment: Definitely agree, breaking up the logarithm gets rid of using the quotient rule

Answer (score 3):

It would also be advantageous here to apply a property of logarithms, specifically:
$$
\ln(a/b)=\ln(a)-\ln(b).
$$
Applying this to your given equation will considerably simplify your derivative, as it will eliminate your need to use the quotient rule as part of your chain rule calculation.

Answer (score 3):

I would NOT use the chain rule before doing this:
\begin{align}
f(x) = \ln\frac{x+2}{x^3-1} & = \ln (x+2) - \ln(x^3-1) \\[10pt]
& = \ln(x+2) - \ln((x-1)(x^2+x+1)) \\[10pt]
& = \ln(x+2) - \ln(x+1) - \ln(x^2+x+1).
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that you know that the derivative of $y=\ln(x)$ is $y'=\dfrac{1}{x}$, and you know the chain rule that gives the derivative of a composite function:
$y=f(g(x)) \rightarrow y'=f'(g(x))g'(x)$.

Use these  and you have:

$$y=\ln\frac{x+2}{x^3-1} \rightarrow y'=\frac{x^3-1}{x+2} \left(\frac{x+2}{x^3-1} \right)'$$

Now use the derivative of a fraction.... and you find the result.

Answer (score 1):

Look up the chain rule on youtube. There is a lot of songs ect that will make this easy as cake.

Answer (score 1):

$$f'_{(x)}=\frac{1}{\frac{x+2}{x^3-1}}\left (\frac{(x^3+1)-(x+2)3x^2}{(x^3-1)^2}\right)$$
$$f'_{(x)}=\frac{-(2x^3+6x^2-1)}{(x+2)(x^3-1)}$$

Comment: would the first term then become x^3-1/x+2?

Comment: yes.now you can simplify this.

Comment: @Cheng I have edited the answer.

Comment: Innumerable postings here recommend this needlessly complicated way of doing this.